# After running Linear regression on my dataset,my RMSE is coming 1109.181

Tags: linear-regression

I am running Linear regression on a medicinal dataset.

```
[columns:'Medicine_ID','Counterfeit_Weight','DistArea_ID','Active_Since','Medicine_MRP','Medicine_Type','SidEffect_Level','Availability_rating','Area_Type','Area_City_Type','Area_dist_level','Counterfeit_Sales]
```

After completing the data cleaning part I try to run Linear Regression( as I was predicting Counterfeit_sales).but my RMSE is coming "1109.18". Please advice me what has gone wrong?

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train,test=train_test_split(cf_train,random_state=123,test_size=0.2)
x_train=train.drop(["Medicine_ID","Counterfeit_Sales"],1)
y_train=train["Counterfeit_Sales"]
x_test=train.drop(["Medicine_ID","Counterfeit_Sales"],1)
y_test=train["Counterfeit_Sales"]

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lm=LinearRegression()
p_test=lm.predict(x_test)
residual=p_test-y_test
rmse=np.sqrt(np.dot(residual,residual)/len(p_test))
```

Comment: Squared Error (SE) = numpy.square(residual), Mean Squared Error (MSE) = numpy.mean(SE), Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE) = numpy.sqrt(MSE). Try calculating as "RMSE = numpy.sqrt(numpy.mean(numpy.square(residual)))" and compare the result to your current calculation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply James. I tried calculating RMSE on your given formula. The result is same as earlier i.e 1109.181.